# Updating DataContext property at runtime not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not sure how this works in WPF and C#. It is still quick confusing. I have a `TabControl` that I want to show either when the property on `x:Class` or DataContext is true. I assign DataContext to my window like this;

```
private ModelObject DataContextModel = new ModelObject()
{
    Minutes = 0,
    Hour = 0
};

...

this.DataContext =  DataContextModel
```

The ModelObject looks like this;

```
public class ModelObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    bool LiveScrapingValue = true;
    public bool LiveScraping
    {
        get { return LiveScrapingValue; }
        set
        {
            LiveScrapingValue = value;
        }
    }
    ...
```

My TabControl element looks like this;

```
<TabControl Name="ScraperLiveAttorneysTabControl" Visibility="{Binding LiveScraping, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

I know I am supposed to create a bool to visibility converter so I have created one on my x:Class;

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value == true)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

..and the resource to go with it;

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

Now I am having problems access the this.DataContext data that I set and changing the property `LiveScraping` to true or false to display or hide the TabControl. My approach is simply to use;

```
DataContextModel.LiveScraping = true;
```

But this does not work because `this.DataContext` is no not pointing to DataContextModel

Comment: LiveScraping property setter doesnot do INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the propertychanged event.

Comment: It does not work after adding; `OnPropertyChanged("LiveScraping");` I think my problem is not being able to access the `this.DataContext =  DataContextModel` afterwards. I don't know how to change a property after it has been set. I think this is not enough `DataContextModel.LiveScraping = true;` since `DataContextModel` is not `this.DataContext`

Comment: But you have previously assigned `this.DataContext =  DataContextModel`, so `DataContextModel` and `this.DataContext` refer to the same object. It should work, provided your OnPropertyChanged implementation is correct, and you call it *after* setting the backing field value.

Comment: There's also a built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter. You don't need to write your own.

Comment: @Clemens I think he is returning hidden with the converter

Comment: @Clemens I was playing around with that. I have changed it. The `OnPropertyChanged` was the problem. It works now. Is there a way to pass parameters to my `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` so that I can say specifically when to show the element when the property value is what.

Comment: Set the `ConverterParameter` property of the Binding. It's passed to the `parameter` argument of the Convert method.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. So in c# objects are always assigned to (properties/variables) by references? Or is this just a unique behavior for this.DataContext. So if I say; `private ModelObject DataContextModel = new ModelObject()` and `ModelObject AnotherProperty=DataContextModel` and If I change `AnotherProperty.SomeProperty=true` I should expect `DataContextModel.SomeProperty` to be true. I see this a lot in c# I just wonder whether there are some limitations.